# Compilation error depends on 'use' order

Tags: perl

I have these three files

Constants/Requests.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use base 'Exporter';

use constant MR_NOACTION     =>   0;
use constant MR_START        =>   1;
use constant MR_STOP         =>   2;

our @EXPORT = (
    'MR_NOACTION',
    'MR_START',
    'MR_STOP'
);
1;
```

JobManDB.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package JobManDB;

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant WEB_DB_FILE    => "db/web.db";
use constant MASTER_DB_FILE => "db/master.db";

use Constants::Requests;

sub new
{
    print "Ahoj: " . MR_NOACTION . "\n";
    ...
```

Master.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Master;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::HiRes qw( usleep );
use Data::Dumper;

use JobManDB;                   # use #1

use Constants::Requests;  # use #2

...
```

Program as posted is working, if but if I swith `use #1` with `use #2` the compilation fails with error:

```
Bareword "MR_NOACTION" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at lib/JobManDB.pm line 26.
```

(line 26 is the line in 'new' subroutine). I would like to know why. Thank you.

EDIT:
Another issue is, that if I add line `package Requests;` at the beginning of Requests.pm, the compilation fails with the same error but independently on order of 'uses'.

Comment: Is that a typo in `Requests.pm` or `use Constants::MasterRequests`? You seems to be requiring different file from this example.

Comment: no sorry, I changed the filename for this example, I'll correct it in code

Comment: Also - are you really missing the "package" declaration in Constants::...Requests?

Comment: The `package` line must read `package Constants::Requests;` and not just `package Requests;`.

Comment: I added 'package Requests;` line on the beginning and now the compilation fails in both cases.

Comment: @MoritzBunkus, Thats the answer, could you please post it and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Requests.pm` file is missing its package declaration, `package Constants::Requests;`.